# Xcode 8.2.1 crashes on opening project with array index out of bounds

Tags: xcode, crash

I just upgraded to Xcode 8.2.1 and Xcode crashes every time I open my project with the following traceback.  I verified that an older version of Xcode (8.1) can still open the project file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8C1002
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Creation Backtrace for Notification Token:

  0   -[_DVTNotificationReceiver initWithBlock:queue:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) dvt_addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  2   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource setRootItems:] (in IDEKit)
  3   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView _updateRootItems:sortDescriptors:] (in IDEKit)
  4   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView setRootItems:] (in IDEKit)
  5   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView _updateBoundContentArrayOrSet] (in IDEKit)
  6   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView updateBoundContentArray] (in IDEKit)
  7   -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) updateBoundValueForBinding:] (in DVTKit)
  8   -[DVTBindingHelper observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTKit)
  9   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 10   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 11   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 12   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 13   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator updateScopeItems:] (in IDEKit)
 14   __44-[IDEBatchFindNavigator setupLocationPicker]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
 15   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) _dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:owner:creationBacktrace:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 16   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 17   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator setupLocationPicker] (in IDEKit)
 18   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator viewDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 19   -[DVTViewController _viewDidInstall] (in DVTKit)
 20   -[_DVTViewController_ViewLifecycleInterpositions viewDidMoveToWindow] (in DVTKit)
 21   -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 22   -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 23   __42-[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 24   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 25   -[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController] (in DVTKit)
 26   -[DVTReplacementView installedViewController] (in DVTKit)
 27   -[DVTReplacementView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 28   -[DVTLayoutView_ML _reallyLayoutIfNeededTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 29   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 30   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 31   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 32   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 33   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 34   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 35   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
 36   -[DVTLayoutView_ML viewWillDraw] (in DVTKit)
 37   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 38   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 39   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 40   -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] (in AppKit)
 41   -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 42   -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 43   ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke6365 (in AppKit)
 44   __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 45   CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) (in QuartzCore)
 46   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore)
 47   CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore)
 48   CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) (in QuartzCore)
 49   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 50   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 51   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 52   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 53   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 54   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 55   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 56   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 57   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 58   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 59   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 60   start (in libdyld.dylib)

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource outlineView:child:ofItem:] (in IDEKit)
  5   refreshRowEntryItemAndLevelInfo (in AppKit)
  6   -[NSOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] (in AppKit)
  7   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] (in IDEKit)
  8   __83-[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:]_block_invoke.735 (in IDEKit)
  9   +[NSAnimationContext(DVTNSAnimationContextAdditions) dvt_nonAnimatedBlock:] (in DVTKit)
 10   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView suspendEditingWhilePerformingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 11   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:] (in IDEKit)
 12   DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 13   __48-[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:]_block_invoke.42 (in DVTFoundation)
 14   -[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 16   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 17   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 18   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 19   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
 20   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 21   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 22   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 23   -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _postNotificationNamed:forChangedItems:] (in IDEKit)
 24   -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _delayedPostGraphAndPropertyChangeNotifications] (in IDEKit)
 25   __48-[DVTDelayedInvocation initWithTarget:selector:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 26   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 27   __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 28   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 29   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 30   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 31   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 32   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 33   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 34   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 35   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 36   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 37   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 38   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 39   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 40   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSRangeException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9993a452 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106127762 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 194
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff882b8f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99851725 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 245
4   IDEKit                              0x000000010776c830 -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource outlineView:child:ofItem:] + 190
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff86d092e5 refreshRowEntryItemAndLevelInfo + 327
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff86d02f67 -[NSOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] + 3024
7   IDEKit                              0x0000000107767d7b -[IDENavigatorOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] + 357
8   IDEKit                              0x000000010776ac2e __83-[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:]_block_invoke.735 + 522
9   DVTKit                              0x000000010685464f +[NSAnimationContext(DVTNSAnimationContextAdditions) dvt_nonAnimatedBlock:] + 132
10  IDEKit                              0x0000000107765441 -[IDENavigatorOutlineView suspendEditingWhilePerformingBlock:] + 101
11  IDEKit                              0x000000010776a76d -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:] + 2226
12  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106127576 DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint + 100
13  DVTFoundation                       0x00000001060e1f32 __48-[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:]_block_invoke.42 + 149
14  DVTFoundation                       0x00000001060e1c7f -[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:] + 1054
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998c5b1c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998c5aaf ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998c5a27 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998c5792 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99882542 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99881795 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
21  Foundation                          0x00007fff9718e17a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
22  DVTFoundation                       0x00000001060e338a -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 360
23  IDEKit                              0x000000010794c00f -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _postNotificationNamed:forChangedItems:] + 542
24  IDEKit                              0x000000010794c35d -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _delayedPostGraphAndPropertyChangeNotifications] + 713
25  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105ef15a8 __48-[DVTDelayedInvocation initWithTarget:selector:]_block_invoke + 79
26  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105ef298b -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] + 257
27  Foundation                          0x00007fff9726884a __NSFirePerformWithOrder + 339
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998cefc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998cef37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998ae408 __CFRunLoopRun + 872
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998ade38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87c2b935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
33  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87c2b76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
34  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87c2b5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff869a2df6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff869a2226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
37  DVTKit                              0x00000001066d1eaf -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 396
38  AppKit                              0x00007fff86996d80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
39  AppKit                              0x00007fff86960368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
40  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff94a015ad start + 1
41  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: For me...deleting Derived Data content worked!

Comment: @JayprakashDubey It will work until you hit Find Navigator few times and then will crash again, and you will have to clean derived data again and so on... Very buggy release.

Answer (score 19):

Ok, well I managed to fix this issue by deleting my .xcworkspace directory and recreating it via `pod install`.  Xcode opens and I'm able to build my project.

**Edit**:
As others have suggested a better solution is to delete the xcuserdata directory from within .xcworkspace.  This is faster as you don't need to re-run pod install every time.

Comment: I was also able to "fix" the issue (after forced into xcode update) by opening the .xcworkspace directory (show pakcage contents) and then get rid of the xcuserdata folder.

Comment: Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela, thanks for your answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer is from [Lukasz's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265637/xcode-8-2-1-crashes-on-opening-project-with-array-index-out-of-bounds/268151#comment335262_265744):

1. **Right click** on the file `.xcworkspace` > **Show Package Contents**
2. **Delete** the `xcuserdata` folder

And now Xcode will open the project workspace just fine.

Comment: This is same as that of @Eric answer

Comment: @Jayprakash He edited his answer directly after I added this answer. His edit was at 20:17:4 UTC and this answer was posted at 19:52:17 UTC.

Comment: This might work too. But if the issue returns back after some time (mostly when using Find Navigator).

Comment: I think you need a 3rd point : 3. Run pod install/update.
Thanks

Comment: This method works. I tried restart the whole MacOS, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

For others experiencing a similar issue, but this only happens when the Find Navigator is toggled in the navigator area. Try clicking on the Project Navigator or `CMD + 1` repeatedly upon launch. Sounds funny but it works.

Comment: FYI, it may fail the first couple of times.

Comment: Yeah, a bit funny, but mostly sad. I am having the same problem and if i don't use Find Navigator, it doesn't crash at all. This version of Xcode, sadly, sucks big time.

Answer (score 1):

Besides deleting the `xcuserdata` folder in the project's workspace directory, I was also able to remedy this particular crash by deleting derived data (either for the project that was open while Xcode crashed, or for all projects) at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Last time Xcode crashed I had to do both things to be able to start Xcode again, so I think deleting both is your safest bet (for now at least).

Answer (score 0):

- yes deleting xcuserdata helps.
- I used to wipe the Derived Data but
  then it would crash again immediately on Reopen if I tried to do anything
  before indexing finished again.
- I noticed that it only happened on a
  personal project I edited at home and in work.
- The username was
  different on both so I ended up with 2 user entries in xcuserdata my
  work login username and my home username.
- I notice that both have
  Breakpoints.
- And the error thrown is
  _IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource so its something on the LHS side panels in Xcode?
- Can you add a .ignore for xcuserdata without messing
  up a workspace?

[image]